# The conditional expectation of a geometric brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30705/conditional-expectation-of-a-geometric-brownian-motion?newreg=1593c9b8fbd942f8a8452000273074a0) it states that 
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma(W_t-W_s)}|\mathcal{F}_s] = \mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma(W_t-W_s)}],$$
and I assume that $0 \leq s \leq t$.
The accepted answer states that this step is correct. However, how can the random variable (LHS) ever be equal to a constant (RHS) for all $0 \leq s \leq t$? The only situation in which it seems to be true is when $s=0$, since the LHS then collapses to a constant as well. Can anybody provide an explanation?

Comment: What do you know about the increments of a brownian motion?

Comment: Independent and  $W_t - W_s \sim N(0, t-s)$. So do you mean that $\mathbb{E}(e^{\sigma(W_t-W_s)}|\mathcal{F_s}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{\sigma(W_{t-s}-W_0)}|\mathcal{F_0}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{\sigma W_{t-s}}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{\sigma( W_t-W_s)})$?

Comment: The independent increments imply that $W_t-W_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$ and therefore is the conditional expectation equal to the expectation $\mathbb{E}[W_t-W_s |\mathcal{F}_s ] =\mathbb{E}[W_t-W_s] $. This also holds if you apply continuous functions on $W_t-W_s$.

Comment: The question you referenced says this:$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma W(t)}|{\cal F}_s] = 
\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma (W(t) - W(s) + W(s))}|{\cal F}_s] = 
\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma (W(t) - W(s))}|{\cal F}_s]e^{W(s)}
$$ Could you clarify where you get the above equation from please?

Comment: It's the third equality in the question